# Laravel: Catch all nonexistent pages

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to make a 404 page for all nonexistent pages.
For example I have this code

```
public function category($category)
    {
        $category = Category::find($category);
        if($category === null) return abort(404); // return 404 page with 404 header status error
        return view('pages.category', compact('category'));
    }
```

My routes file

```
Route::get('/category/{category}', 'CategoryController@category');
```

I have another components like subcategories, articles, reviews and etc. In first case I can type *app/category/1234*.
If my app doesn't have category where id = 1234 in category table then without checking **variable === null** I can get a default but empty page and it will be with a 200 http status. It's not normal.

I can check for *null* in all components but I think it's not correct.

And one more question about SQL error. "id" field have integer type and if I go to *app/category/1sdsds* in browser I will get

> SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, checking on NULL is the only way to catch errors before they break anything else. There is a way to create custom 404 pages, Just create a page at `resources/assets/views/errors/404.blade.php`. You could also use `findOrFail`, if an error is caught, a 404 will be called. It's kindof a shortcut.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets Laravel knows you are accepting only integer

```
Route::get('/category/{category}', 'CategoryController@category')->where('category', '[0-9]+');
```

For the controller

```
public function category(Category $category){...}
```

If not find it should return 404 page. You don't need another checks and don't need to assign $category, it will be already assigned.

Another way will be

```
public function category($category){
    $category = Category::firstOrFail($category);
}
```

Comment: I use `findOrFail($category)` instead of `firstOrfail($category)`. Thanks a lot! It's working now.

Comment: by the way you have a little misprint in your code above. Not `[0-9+]`, it should be `[0-9]+`. I found this when the id of my new category became more than 10.